# Rank of a union of a set

Tags: set-theory

I'm exploring the Von Neumann Universe and specifically trying to determine rank($\cup x$) in terms of rank($x$). The answer seems to be depending on whether rank($x$) is a successor, or a limit ordinal. I've already shown that for limit ordinals $\alpha$, we have $\cup \alpha = \alpha$, so their ranks coincide as well. The proof of the case where $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal however, eludes me.

Comment: Have you observed yet that $\bigcup(\alpha+1)=\alpha$?

Comment: I am aware of that fact. Not sure how to apply it here though...? Since $x$ need not be an ordinal.

Comment: Well, the ranks of its members are ordinals.

Comment: Ah yes, so if rank and union operators commute, I would have it, since then rank($\bigcup x$) = $\bigcup$ rank($x$) = $\bigcup \gamma + 1 = \gamma$, say

Comment: Yeah. But it's simpler, honestly. Just write the definition of $\bigcup x$, and then write the rank definition for that set, and see if you can notice the obvious connection between the two.

Comment: Do you mean the following?

rank($\bigcup x$) = min{$\beta \mid \{z \mid (\exists y \in x)(z \in y)\} \subseteq V_{\beta} $}
Or the definition rank($x$) = $\bigcup \{rank(y)+1 \mid y \in x\}$?

Comment: Sorry if I asked too many questions, I'm new here and this my very first post :) Still have to learn the etiquette around here. I'm now assuming it was the latter "definition", although in my text that was a result, obtained from the definition rank($x$) = min{.....}.

Comment: I seem to have exhausted all of my possibilities now, and yet I just can't show the inclusion $\bigcup \{ \text{rank}(y) + 1 \mid y \in x\} \subseteq \{ \text{rank}(z) + 1 \mid z \in \bigcup x\} $

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{rank}(\cup x)=\sup\{\text{rank}(y)+1:y\in\cup x\}$$
$$\leq\sup\{\text{rank}(y):y\in x\}\leq \text{rank}(\cup x)$$

Therefore $\text{rank}(\cup x)=\sup\{\text{rank}(y):y\in x\}$. If the $\sup$ is attained then
$$\text{rank}(\cup x)+1=\text{rank}( x)$$
and if the $\sup$ is not attained then
$$\text{rank}(\cup x)=\text{rank}( x)$$